# PHP cannot access local file

Tags: php

I'm trying to simply write to a text file with PHP and every time I try it doesn't return an error but just doesn't write. I'm doing...

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1') or die('error');
fclose($fp);
```

And very time it returns "error". `file.txt` is definitely in the same directory as the PHP file. I figured PHP couldn't get access to the file. I'm using Windows Server 2008. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Show errors and all shall be revealed http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors

Answer (score 1):

Two things can be happening.

One, consider setting the full path to the file within the directory like this; change `/full/path/to/the/file/` to match the actual full path to the file:

```
$fp = fopen('/full/path/to/the/file/file.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1') or die('error');
fclose($fp);
```

Next, does the file itself have permissions that allow the server itself to access it. Remember, the Apache server will run as another user other than you. So need to make sucre the ownership & permissions match the Apache user.