# I want to push html input text to text(.txt) file

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Simple Sign up from</title>
  <head>
    
    <style>
      html, body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      }
      form {
      border: 5px solid #f1f1f1;
      }
      input[type=text] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 16px 8px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      select {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 16px 8px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      button {
      background-color: #4286f4;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 0;
      margin: 10px 0;
      border: none;
      cursor: grab;
      width: 48%;
      }
      h1 {
      text-align:center;
      fone-size:18;
      }
      button:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
      }
      .formcontainer {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 24px 50px 12px;
      }
      .container {
      padding: 20px 0;
      text-align:left;
      }
      span.psw {
      float: right;
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-right: 15px;
      }
      /* Change styles for span on extra small screens */
      @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      span.psw {
      display: block;
      float: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <h1>DSL_PROJECT</h1>
      <div class="formcontainer">
      <div class="container">
        <label for="Rname"><strong>Requestor-name</strong></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Requestor-name" name="Rname" required>
        <label for="Nname"><strong>Namespace-name</strong></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Namespace-name" name="Nname" required>
         <label for="Pname"><strong>Project_ID</strong></label>
        <select id="select">
         <option value="default">default</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit"><strong>SUBMIT</strong></button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>

var select=document.getElementById("select"),
      arr=["p1","p2","p3"];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{ 
   var option=document.createElement("OPTION"),
      txt=document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
   option.appendChild(txt);
   option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
   select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

> 

From the above HTML code  there are few user inputs so I have added Post method & PHP code to trigger or push input user data of html to text(.txt)file but data is not written to the text file[ I have created manually data.txt file in my local]. And in the same script added java script to add or create list.Someone help me to fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't test this right now though two errors you made are in your `<form>` tag and in your `POST` lines. The form needs to have an action attribute to trigger your php. `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">` should work. That line means the file will call the php in itself when the form is submitted. Secondly, you are not actually using post to get your data. From what I can see, `textdata` is not defined anywhere in your code so post can't find it. You need to have something in the `name` attribute in the post line. Like `$_POST['Rname']` instead

Comment: Please tell me if my last comment worked for you, if it did I'll add it as an answer in case anyone in the future has a similar issue

Comment: i'm getting below error like "Your file couldn’t be accessed"

Comment: try the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225206/php-cannot-access-local-file . Someone on that page says it might be a permissions error (which is what I think it is) though he doesn't list a solution. You should just be able to google "how to let other users write to another file on *your operating system*" to fix that

Comment: tried with the above solution still i'm in the state. Could some one help me on the same.

Comment: I have given full permission to the text(.txt) file now I could data storing into file.Thanks